# Change the height of parent UITableView cell based on the height of child TableViewControllers

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

```
WidgetsVC(has a table view and uses tableview automatic dimension)

    ->ListVC(uses tableview automatic dimension and embedded as a row inside WidgetVC)

        ->TableViewCell-Image(embedded inside ListVC)
```

The images are downloaded from the network and each image has its own height. So when the images are loaded how do I change the height of the row in WidgetVC?

WidgetsVC can contain multiple ListVC

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are embedding `UIViewController`s inside a `UITableViewCell`, you can't rely on Auto Layout to make height changes according to loaded images automatically.

Therefore, I suggest you to move your Image loading logic to `WidgetsVC` and perform the following actions each time an image is loaded.

1. Calculate the height/width aspect ratio of the loaded image (if your image loading library has a completion handler, you can use that for the calculation purpose).
2. Calculate the fitting height of the image (this is still in the image loader's completion handler in `WidgetVC`).

```swift
let imageHeight = aspectRatio * self.tableView.frame.width
```

3. Store the image and it's calculated fitting height in a data structure.
4. Invoke `tableView.reloadData()` at the end of the completion handler introduced in step 1.
5. In your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method, pass in the height stored in the data structure.
6. In your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method, pass in the image stored in the data structure.

An example of a data structure you can use in step 3 above is shown below.

```swift
struct WidgetListImageModel{
    var height: CGFloat
    var image: UIImage
}

var widgetImageModels: [Int: WidgetListImageModel] = [:]
```

Note that `widgetImageModels` is a `Dictionary` because of the following reasons.

1. You might already have a data model which is passed at `WidgetVC`'s `cellForRowAt` method, so instead of modifying it you can store the information needed independently.
2. You can easily query `widgetImageModels` for the information you need by using the `indexPath.row` as the index at both your `heightForRowAt` and `cellForRowAt` methods.
3. You do not have to maintain the index of the cell you wish to load data for inside `WidgetListImageModel`.

The above steps assume many things about your current implementation since you haven't provided any code. Please let me know if you have questions or if the answer doesn't apply to your code specifically. Will try my best to help you out.

Cheers!